# How to store user input as a variable using input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, user-input

This is what I have so far in HTML:

```
<input id="userinput" type="text"><br><br>
<a id="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  Add to List
</a>

<div id="tasklist" class="col-md-12">
  <a id="item1"></a>
  <a id="item2"></a>
  <a id="item3"></a>
  <a id="item4"></a>
</div>
```

And in Javascript I have:

```
var counter = 0;

$("#submit").click(function(){
  counter = counter + 1;
  $("#newtask").hide();

$("#item", counter).attr("text", userinput);
});
```

I am having issues with the .attr function and its formatting. I also do not understand how to refer back to the user's input and save it as a variable or use the id tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$("#item", counter).attr("text", $("userinput").val());
```

Comment: are you trying to put text inside the input as a text into the tasklist ?

Comment: I am trying to post the text to the page as a part of a list, which I will make into a checklist

Comment: I'm not sure it is what you want?
$("#item"+counter).html( $("userinput").val());

Answer (score 0):

In java script con-concatenation operator is '+' not ','. Also use 'html' instead of 'attr'. Please check the below code, it may help you.

```js
var counter = 0;

$("#submit").click(function(){
  counter = counter + 1;
  $("#newtask").hide();
  userinput = $('#userinput').val();
$("#item"+counter).html(userinput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="userinput" type="text"><br><br>
<a id="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  Add to List
</a>

<div id="tasklist" class="col-md-12">
  <a id="item1"></a>
  <a id="item2"></a>
  <a id="item3"></a>
  <a id="item4"></a>
</div>
```